# mysql select row two times with diffrent dates

Tags: mysql

I have a table width rows that have two datets one reminder date and one end date. I would liket to put these events in a calendar based on the two dates so I need to select each row two times in order by the two date fields. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Are you looking for `BETWEEN`?

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like

```
SELECT  CalendarID,
        CalendarName,
        CalendarDescription,
        ReminderDate EntryDate,
        'Reminder' EntryType
FROM    Calendar
WHERe   ReminderDate = YourDate
UNION ALL
SELECT  CalendarID,
        CalendarName,
        CalendarDescription,
        EndDate EntryDate,
        'End' EntryType
FROM    Calendar
WHERe   EndDate = YourDate
```

The first part will bring back all entries where the reminder date is on the date specified, and the second part will bring back all entries with end date specified.

You could also change the where clause to a between

so something like

```
SELECT  CalendarID,
        CalendarName,
        CalendarDescription,
        ReminderDate EntryDate,
        'Reminder' EntryType
FROM    Calendar
WHERe   ReminderDate BETWEEN YourLookupStartDate and YourLookupEndDate
UNION ALL
SELECT  CalendarID,
        CalendarName,
        CalendarDescription,
        EndDate EntryDate,
        'End' EntryType
FROM    Calendar
WHERe   ReminderDate BETWEEN YourLookupStartDate and YourLookupEndDate
```

Answer (score 0):

It may help

```
SELECT column_name
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name BETWEEN Remainderdate AND Enddate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query

```
SELECT * FROM table1 as a
INNER JOIN table1 as b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a. reminder_date = 'reminder_date_here' and b. end_date ='end_date_here'
```